# Difference between int(input()) and input(int()) in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

when I type code as int(input()) and input(int()) for same input let say 12,output are 12 and 012 respectively . So why this,what is difference in syntax?

Comment: With int(input()) you're casting the return value of the input() function call to an integer. With input(int()) you're using int() as a prompt for the user input. Since you don't pass int() an argument, it returns zero. In your case, the output of input(int) is the string '12' but the output of int(input()) is the integer 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int()` returns the integer 0. `input()` is using this as the `prompt` argument (which it prints out to stdout). Hence the extra `0` being printed in the front.

Answer (score 1):

input() can take some text as parameter as description of the input-line.

From the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input):

```py
>>> s = input('--> ')  
--> Monty Python's Flying Circus
>>> s  
"Monty Python's Flying Circus"
```

int() is zero and therefore you pass zero to input if you do that:

```py
# --> same as input(0):
input(int())
```

If you write int(input()) you first get the input which is a string and then cast it to an int:

```py
>>> type(input())
5
<class 'str'>
>>> type(int(input()))
5
<class 'int'>
>>>
```